# Should I always rely on httptest.ResponseRecorder.Result() in my assertions?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I was writing some tests for a Golang REST API handler which is tested using `httptest`:

```
func TestT(t *testing.T) {
    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    ctx, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(rr)
    ctx.Request, _ = http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/path", http.NoBody)

    MyHandler(ctx)

    resp := rr.Result()
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    assert.Equal(t, http.StatusBadRequest, resp.StatusCode)
}
```

Question is that I've seen many people directly testing from the recorder instead of the response returned by `Result()`, like:

```
assert.Equal(t, http.StatusBadRequest, rr.Code)
assert.Equal(t, string(body), rr.Body.String())
```

I know what `Result()` is doing and guarantying, but what is the clean and best practice around testing with `httptest.ResponseRecorder`?

Comment: Some fields of a ResultRecorder are deprecated as you sure know because you red the documentation, didn't you? It should be clear not to use deprecated fields. For Code: It's not deprecated and if its 0 value doesn't bother you it's okay to use it. All said it should be pretty clear what to do: Use Result. While we are talking about idiomatic: Your assert.Equal instead of `if ... == ...` bothers me more than use of Code.